# How to select a single expression from inside a list

Tags: python

Previously on my GCSE NEA computing assessment I asked for some help with some 2-D lis s,and with help from several members (including a member called dshort) I was able to achieve what the first step was that I required. Now I need to select a single expression so that it outputs one question and allows the user to input an answer instead of showing the whole list of questions individually.

```
def easy():
  stageone = [["carry on waywardson" , "Kansas"],
              ["Back In Black", "Ac/DC"],
              ["smoke on the water", "Deep purple"],
              ["sweet home albama", "Lynard Skynyrd"],
              ["another brick in the wall","Pink Floyd"]]
  for entry in stageone:
      shortTitle = ' '.join([word[0] for word in entry[0].split(' ')])
      print(shortTitle, entry[1])
```

I require one of the songs and writers to be outputted so then I can code to allow the user to enter their answer.

As currently when I run my code it will out put all the songs first letters and artist names instead of doing it so that the user can answer it.

(Big thanks again to the dshort for providing me with this piece of code.)

Comment: `print(stageone[0])` only first entry will get printed.

Comment: Which song do you want?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I want the first song so carry on wayward son to be printed first

Comment: @RajanChauhan would I also have to do the same each time around for every song that I have in the list

Comment: Try  `for entry in stageone:
      shortTitle = entry[0]
      print(shortTitle)`  to just print each song on a separate line.

Comment: 1. convert `easy` to a generator method instead by changing `print(shortTitle, entry[1])` to `yeild (shortTitle, entry[1])`
2. create generator object as x = easy()
3. Call print(next(x)) multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *yield* statement to produce your items as you need it:

> A generator is a type of collection that produces items on-the-fly and can only be iterated once. By using generators you can improve your application's performance and consume less memory as compared to normal collections, so it provides a nice boost in performance.

From [here](https://stackabuse.com/understanding-pythons-yield-keyword/)

So in your code you just need to change the *print* to *yield* and then use the *next()* method to get the item from your generator.

```py
def easy():
  stageone = [["carry on waywardson" , "Kansas"],
              ["Back In Black", "Ac/DC"],
              ["smoke on the water", "Deep purple"],
              ["sweet home albama", "Lynard Skynyrd"],
              ["another brick in the wall","Pink Floyd"]]
  for entry in stageone:
      shortTitle = ' '.join([word[0] for word in entry[0].split(' ')])
      yield (shortTitle, entry[1])
yieldPoint = easy()
#Question
print(next(yieldPoint)) #('c o w', 'Kansas')
#Question
print(next(yieldPoint)) #('B I B', 'Ac/DC')
```